# Mongodb + Mongoose: trying to add a sub-sub-item

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Does this makes any sense when trying to add a sub-sub-item? (I'm new to mongo - be merciful :-))

```
question = db.questions.findOne({_id: ObjectId("529c5d44211c9a8c11000006")})
question.answers[0].votes.insert(...)
```

When I run this from the mongo console the result is an error saying [object object] does not have the method insert.

I have the following mongoDB Question Schema.

```
{
    "__v" : 2,
    "_creator" : ObjectId("529c5d2d211c9a8c11000005"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("529c5d44211c9a8c11000006"),
    "answers" : [
    {
        "postDate" : ISODate("2013-12-02T10:14:19.060Z"),
        "postDateText" : "15min ago",
        "authorEmail" : "guys@pix.com",
        "authorName" : "guys@pix.com",
        "body" : "You need magic powder",
        "isWinner" : false,
        "_creator" : ObjectId("529c5d2d211c9a8c11000005"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("529c5d7b211c9a8c11000008"),
        "votes" : [
            {
                "voteType" : "up",
                "_creator" : ObjectId("529c5d2d211c9a8c11000005"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("529c5d5b211c9a8c11000007")
            }
        ]
    }
],
    "authorEmail" : "guys@wix.com",
    "authorName" : "guys@wix.com",
    "body" : "I'm trying to fly...\n\n<pre class=\"brush: js;\">\nfunction logName(name) {\n    console.log(name);\n}\n</pre>",
    "isResolved" : false,
    "postDate" : ISODate("2013-12-02T10:13:24.235Z"),
    "tags" : [
    "fly"
],
    "title" : "How do I fly?",
    "views" : [],
    "votes" : [
    {
        "voteType" : "up",
        "_creator" : ObjectId("529c5d2d211c9a8c11000005"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("529c5d5b211c9a8c11000007")
    }
]
}
```

I'm trying, given a questionId and an answerId to add a vote to the votes array (which is inside the answer). I can't seem to do it. Help?

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to try and do this to your question?

Comment: Sure, I've added the methods I use in the console at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` is for adding whole new documents; when you just want to add a new element to an array field of an existing document, you can use `update` along with an operator like `$push`.

So, in the shell you would use something like this:

```js
db.questions.update(
    {_id: ObjectId("529c5d44211c9a8c11000006")},
    {'answers.0.votes': {$push: voteToPush}})
```